# Calculating a cumulative deviation from mean monthly value in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

How would I use pandas to calculate a cumulative deviation from a mean monthly rainfall value?

I am given daily rainfall data (e.g. s, below) which I can convert to a pd.Series and resample into monthly periods (sum; e.g. sm, below). But I then want to calculate the difference between each monthly value and the mean for the month. I have added a synthetic example:

```
rng = pd.period_range(20010101, 20131231, freq='D')
s = pd.Series(np.random.normal(2.5,2,size=len(rng)), index=rng)
sm = s.resample('M', how='sum')
```

For example, for January 2010 I would like to calculate the difference between the value for that month and the average monthly rainfall for January (over a long period). Then I want a cumulative sum of that difference.

I have tried to use the groupby function:

```
sm.groupby(lambda x: x.month).mean()
```

But not successfully. I want each monthly value in 'sm' to have the average for all similar months to be subtracted, then a cumulative sum of that series created. This could be in one step I guess.

How could I achieve this efficiently?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show some example code with some data and with what you tried?

Comment: when you resample resample with both sum and mean..

Comment: I think the answer of @DanAllan is correct for what you want. Try `sm.groupby(sm.index.month).transform(lambda x: x - x.mean()).cumsum().plot()`. It will substract the average of all similar months of each value within that group, and then taking the cumulative sum of it, as you are looking for.

Comment: Great. Yes that works. I just need to work out why! Thanks to both answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is closely related to [an example in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation). This is untested code, but you want something like this:

```
monthly_rainfall = daily_rainfall.resample('D', how=np.sum)
```

To group all Januarys over all the years together (and so on for each month):

```
grouped = monthly_rainfall.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
```

Then

```
deviation = grouped.transform(lambda x: x - x.mean())
deviation.cumsum()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had seen this example in the docs and its close to what I want, but not quite. I have clarified my question with an example code.

Comment: Yes I have tried this and indeed it works. I misinterpreted the transform function. Thanks again.